# Roll/rotate the cube on it's edge

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to Roll/rotate the cube on it's edge?(Like this) [image]

I  read a couple of articles and answers to the questions but still not what I need.All I learned ,is that I need to create a gameobject in the center of the Cube and 4 others on the pivots.Something like that [image]
[image][image]

And what's next, should I use Quaternions or transform.Rotate?Is  the hierarchy correct?

Comment: Is it always going to rotate around this edge or is this a one off thing?

Comment: @JamesHughes To all directions!

Comment: Have you tried using `transform.RotateAround()` and setting the point to the centre of the edge you need? http://answers.unity.com/answers/578650/view.html

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this, it depends on wether you want to rotate around a specific edge or around any of the 12 edges. You could just use RotateAround, which allows you to specify a point (one of the vertex, accesiblr from the MeshFilter component) and an axis; it might not be useful as you dont know which vertex is each one based on its index. If you have something that tells you around which axis to rotate (like s force which triggers the rotation) you can use the first option and use the force to find the vetices and axis that it should rotate around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to tell you to use an external 3D software to set the pivot point to the location in your screenshot but it looks like you want to do this with *multiple* pivot points so you will to use empty GameObjects to accomplish this.

From your screenshot, you seem to be on the right track.

**1**.Create empty GameObjects and position them in the edges you want to rotate the cube around then place them under the cube.

**2**.Use [`transform.RotateAround`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) not  [`transform.Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) to rotate the cube. The first parameter should be the edge pivot point. The second parameter is the axis you want to rotate the cube against. The third one is the angle.

```
//cube to rotate
public GameObject cube;
//Assign dge pos from the editor
public Transform edgePivotPoint;

public float rotSpeed = 60f;

void Update()
{
    cube.transform.RotateAround(edgePivotPoint.position, Vector3.back, rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

---

Note, if rotating the wrong way, try replacing `Vector3.up` with `Vector3.down`, `Vector3.left`, `Vector3.right`, `Vector3.forward` and `Vector3.back`. The one to use depends on your scene setup but trying them will get you to the one

Comment: Is the hierarchy correct?Should I put the centerObject as a child?

Comment: What is centerObject ? I don't know what that is. Just create the edges with empty GameObjects for each edge and then make them child of the cube. That's it.

Comment: It is possible with this logic to make something like that?https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4kQmS3aws0

Comment: That's really some interesting thing. If this is what you are trying to do, use Rigidbody instead. It's made for that. I suggest you first give it a try with a Rigidbody and use AddTorque. If you can't get it to work, create a new question with a title like "How to move/rotate a cube on a surface". You must also link to this video and provide your code that you tried. I will be out for hours but if I return and the problem is still not solved, I will leave an answer in that question.

Comment: I solved it with transform.RotateAround,IEnumerator , centerObject and 4 base Pivots!